# how to show a text field when a specific radio button is selected in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

I want that when I choose `home` then a text field appears on the screen to input some information.
I wrapped the text field with `Visibility` but it didn't work.

```dart
Container(
  margin: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 220,left:0),
  child: RadioListTile(
    title: const Text('home'),
    value: place.home,
    groupValue: selacted,
    onChanged: (place? value) {
      if(place.home==selacted) {
        setState(() {
          isVisible = true;
          selacted= value;
        });
      }
    }
  ),
),
Container(
  margin: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 300,left:0),
  child: Visibility(       
    visible:isVisible,
    child:const TextField(
      decoration: InputDecoration(
        border: OutlineInputBorder(),
        hintText: 'Enter a search term',
      ),
    ),
  ),
),
```

Answer (score 2):

It seems you are comparing the previously selected value.

This should work:

```dart
setState(() {
  _place = value;
  _homeFieldVisible = value == Place.home;
});
```

### Full code sample:

[image]

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

const Color darkBlue = Color.fromARGB(255, 18, 32, 47);

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      theme: ThemeData.dark().copyWith(
        scaffoldBackgroundColor: darkBlue,
      ),
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: HomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const HomePage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<HomePage> createState() => _HomePageState();
}

enum Place { road, home, work }

class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
  Place? _place;
  bool _homeFieldVisible = false;

  void handleSelection(Place? value) {
    setState(() {
      _place = value;
      _homeFieldVisible = value == Place.home;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: SafeArea(
        child: Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16),
          child: Column(
            children: [
              RadioListTile(
                title: const Text('on the road'),
                value: Place.road,
                groupValue: _place,
                onChanged: handleSelection,
              ),
              RadioListTile(
                title: const Text('at home'),
                value: Place.home,
                groupValue: _place,
                onChanged: handleSelection,
              ),
              if (_homeFieldVisible)
                const TextField(
                  decoration: InputDecoration(
                    border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                    hintText: 'Enter a search term',
                  ),
                ),
              RadioListTile(
                title: const Text('at work'),
                value: Place.work,
                groupValue: _place,
                onChanged: handleSelection,
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `onChanged` method should be changed to the following.

```
 onChanged: (place? value) {
            setState(() {
            
              selacted = value;
              if (place.home == selacted) {
                 isVisible = true;
              }
            });
          }
```

Comment: nothing happen nothing appear